# Merge two arrays without override

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I have two arrays that I want to merge into each other but I cannot seem to figure out how to NOT override the properties with the same value/id/number.

What I have now:

First array

```
0: {id: 1, title: "Button", type: "Controls & Inputs"}
1: {id: 2, title: "Switch", type: "Selection Controls"}
2: {id: 3, title: "Tags", type: "Controls & Inputs"}
3: {id: 4, title: "Checkbox", type: "Selection Controls"}
4: {id: 5, title: "Toast", type: "Notifications & Alerts"}
```

Second array

```
0: {id: 1, title: "Colors", type: "Design"}
1: {id: 2, title: "Typography", type: "Design"}
```

**expected output:**

```
0: {id: 1, title: "Button", type: "Controls & Inputs"}
1: {id: 2, title: "Switch", type: "Selection Controls"}
2: {id: 3, title: "Tags", type: "Controls & Inputs"}
3: {id: 4, title: "Checkbox", type: "Selection Controls"}
4: {id: 5, title: "Toast", type: "Notifications & Alerts"}
5: {id: 1, title: "Colors", type: "Design"}
6: {id: 2, title: "Typography", type: "Design"}
```

Comment: You've called these "objects" but your rendering of them looks like they're specifically *array* objects. Is that true?

Comment: no :( i need to only add the second's object values to the first one check the expected output... The second's object properties are addeed to the first one as 5,6

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes that's correct

Comment: So, basically, you just want to `concat` them? `const res = arr1.concat(arr2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look like arrays, not objects. If so, you can use the `concat` method to combine them, like so:

```
let result = [].concat(first, second);
```

or by using the spread operator, like so:

```
let result = [...first, ...second];
```

Comment: This worked! thanks i will rate this an answer in 8 mins

Comment: Good answer. Just FYI, the `.concat()` call doesn't require the useless empty array (and extra object creation). Just do `first.concat(second)`

Comment: For that matter, you could also do `Array.prototype.concat(first, second)` if you wanted to.